# Ubuntu says virtualenv is not installed but pip says it is

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create another virtual environment (I already installed one using the typical instructions found here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) so I run:

```
$ virtualenv experimental
```

> -> The program 'virtualenv' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install virtualenv

I checked to see if perhaps the program needed to be updated:

```
$ pip install virtualenv --upgrade
```

> -> Requirement already up-to-date: virtualenv in /home/uniside/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Any ideas about what is going on here?

Answer (score 17):

Use sudo. Currently it's being install in your local directory.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: how would you run the one inside the local directory? I have the same problem and when adding the `.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to my `PATH` variable, it still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Accept the answer mate or I'm calling the police.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @khrm didn't worked for me.

I was able to do this with  :

```
sudo apt install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems activating my virtualenv projects with Ubuntu's system version, so I just use pip's virtualenv. Works with python2 as well:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```

Just call virutalenv via python3 -m:

```
$ python3 -m virtualenv --help
Usage: virtualenv.py [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```